# How to swap key with other key in dictionary python (NOT with values)

Tags: python, dictionary, swap

I have a dictionary `dct = {'one' : 1, 'two' : 2, 'three' : 3 }` and would like to swap 'one' with 'two' like belows.

`dct = {'two' : 1, 'one' : 2, 'three' : 3}`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It's a simple example. In reality, I have to swap some of key pairs among a lot of keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's typical multi-assignment swap pattern:

```
dct["one"], dct["two"] = dct["two"], dct["one"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
temp = dct["one"]
dct["one"] = dct["two"]
dct["two"] = temp
```